# Docker Engine: Failing to attach via Websocket

Tags: docker, websocket

I want to write a backend to automate running a docker container. For this, Im using the (Api Reference)[https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#attach-to-a-container-websocket]. However, I can't seem to connect to this websocket. I made a test HTML file to test the endpoint:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>
    Send Command
    <input type="text" autofocus>
</label>
<button onclick="sendCommand()">Send</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    const link = "ws://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.24/containers/sharp_hellman/attach/ws?logs=true&stream=true&stdin=true&stdout=true&stderr=true";
    const ws = new WebSocket(link);
    ws.onmessage = (msg) => {
        document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML += msg
    };
    function sendCommand() {
        ws.send(document.querySelector('input').value)
        document.querySelector('input').value = ''
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When looking at the Networking tab in Firefox and Edge, I get an 101 Switching Protocols response:
[image: Response of Docker Engine]
But I do get an error in the console. Depending on which browser I use, the error message changes.

On Firefox:
`The connection to ws://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.24/containers/sharp_hellman/attach/ws?logs=true&stream=true&stdin=true&stdout=true&stderr=true was interrupted while the page was loading.`
On Edge:
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.24/containers/sharp_hellman/attach/ws?logs=true&stream=true&stdin=true&stdout=true&stderr=true' failed: Invalid frame header`

Im on Windows, therefore I use the `Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS`.

When executing docker ps, I get following result:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND    CREATED      STATUS                    PORTS       NAMES
6743bf6743bf   itzg/minecraft-server   "/start"   2 days ago   Up 39 minutes (healthy)   25565/tcp   sharp_hellman
```

How can I make this work so I could attach to the docker-engine via API?

Comment: Are you sure, you're using the correct container name? please post the relevant output of `docker ps`

Comment: Hey @Taxel, thank you for your response. I added the needed info to provide further context. thanks again for trying to help me!